# CAKEPHP conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.5

A car will have a color service, maybe will have a tires service

I am using these tables: car, car_service, certificate, color and tires.

Using CAKEPHP conditions, how can i list the date of the color service and (if exists) the date of the tires service **this line will also have the id of the certificate of the color service.**

I need this query :

```
`SELECT 
    certificate.date,
    cs.date,
    csl.date,
    car.model, 
    tires.brand, 
    car.color 
FROM car
INNER JOIN car_service cs ON cs.color_id = color.id
LEFT JOIN certificate cert ON cert.color_id = cs.color_id`
```

So i end with a table like this one:

```
`Service
-------
service_id| color_id | tires_id | date
111       | 123      |          | 2016-26-04 08:00:00
112       | 123      | 456      | 2016-27-04 09:00:00`
```

I need to get the certificate date, for the **service 111 and for the service 112**.

I try this but just bring the date of the tires service:

```
 $certified= $this->find('first', 
        Array('conditions' => Array('Car.plate' => $plate,
                              'CarService.color_id= color.id',
),
'type' => 'LEFT',
'contain' => Array(
    'Car', 
    'Color' => array('Certificate'),
    'Tires' => array('Certificate')
),
'order' => array('CarService.created DESC'),
'recursive' => -1
)
);
```

`

Comment: Might try cleaning up your example code.  the easier it is to read, the more likely you'll get your answer.  Also, make sure to include what version of Cake you're using.

Comment: Just update the question.

Comment: But with neither of my suggested updates. :/

Comment: I am using cake 2.5.6

Comment: What's the `'type'=>'LEFT'` for?  Your example doesn't show any joins.  Which is also the likely answer:  "you'll need joins".  But I don't understand the question well enough to form an accurate answer.

Comment: I use LEFT because a car maybe a car will have e tires service : LEFT JOIN certificate cert ON cert.color_id = cs.color_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `LEFT`, but are doing so without actually using any `JOIN`s.

Just adding `LEFT` doesn't make your find use JOIN.  You'll need to actually add 'joins' to the array similar to this example:

```
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'car_services',
        'alias' => 'CarService',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'CarService.color_id = Color.id'
        )
    ),
    array( ... // put your left join here
),
```